# How to remove the brackets from the list in python

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
list1 = ['field1','field2','field3']
```

i have used different methods but i is of no help.

```
list1= ( " ".join( repr(e) for e in list1) )
```

but it is printing each character in the string as seperate word like

```
"f","i","e","l","d".
```

But i want the output like:

```
list1='field1','field2','field3'
```

So how can i remove only the brackets from the list without modifying the strings.

Comment: You need to show a **complete** code example, and you need to be clear about the distinction between code and output. You need to explain exactly *what you want to see appear on the screen*, and show *all* the code you use to cause it to appear on the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but maybe `" ".join(list1)`?

Comment: Current code outputs `'field1' 'field2' 'field3'` for me

Answer (score 4):

I *imagine* (the question isn't very clear as noted in the comments) you are looking for:

```
print ",".join(list1)
```

Produces:

```
field1,field2,field3
```

> So how can i remove only the brackets from the list without modifying
>   the strings.

The variable `list1` is a list and the `[]` brackets are included when a list is rendered as a String.  You can provide your own string representation as you have here using `join`.  If you really want to product a string output with the quotes around the strings you could do:

```
print "'" + "','".join(list1) + "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to print your list in a specific format. You can do this using the `print()` function in python3 or the `print` statement in python2.

First, make a string which represents how you want to output your list:

```
output = ",".join("'" + item + "'" for item in list1)
```

There are two steps in this approach. Firstly, we add quotes to the outside of each item in the list, as per your desired output. Secondly, we join the items in the list around a comma.

If you want to have the string 'list1=' at the beginning of the output you can simply prepend it like this:

```
output = 'list1=' + output
```

Then, can simply print this string using `print output` in python2 or `print(output)` in python3.

This should print the following line:

`list1='field1','field2','field3'`

Answer (score 0):

Tada! `str(list1).strip('[').strip(']')`

Not sure if it is possible to get python to output:

> list1='field1','field2','field3'

That is not valid python syntax... (unless defining a tuple):

```
>>>list1='field1','field2','field3'
('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

This is the closest you can get:

```
>>>list1 = ['field1','field2','field3']
# convert list to string
>>>foo = str(list1)
# strip the '[ ]'
>>>print(foo.strip('[').strip(']'))
'field1', 'field2', 'field3'
>>>print("list1=%s" % foo.strip('[').strip(']'))
list1='field1', 'field2', 'field3'
```

Answer (score 0):

most of the previous answers would work, but perhaps the most simplest one is using a for loop:

```
mylist = ['1','2','3','4']

print('list=',end='')
for myvar in mylist:
    print(myvar,end='')

print('')
```

output:

```
list=1234
```

however, this will only work in python 3.4, since you have to use the print function and cannot use a print statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
`list1 = "'" + "','".join(list1) + "'"`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.
e=[1,2,3]
f=re.sub(r'[[]]','',str(e[0]))

Output is : 1